# What is the difference between running devtools::test() in the console and in RStudio build pane?

Tags: r, rstudio, testthat

In a package I am developing, running `devtools::test()` in the console and using "Test" in RStudio's build pane yields different results:

- in the console, all tests are passing with no errors
- in the build pane, one test is failing, and some unexpected text is printed between tests

For context, this package relies on `system()` to call an external program (7-zip in my case):

```r
  cmd = glue('7z e -o"{target_dir}" "{archive}" {pwc} -aoa')
  msg = try(system(cmd, intern=TRUE), silent=TRUE)
```

Debugging this is a massive brain-buster, but it seems that in case of a 7zip error (bad password for this test), this code behaves differently:

- in the console, `msg` contains the whole output, including the error messages:

```r
# [1] ""                                                                                  
# [2] "7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21"               
# [3] ""                                                                                  
# [4] "Scanning the drive for archives:"                                                  
# [5] "1 file, 14085 bytes (14 KiB)"                                                      
# [6] ""                                                                                  
# [7] "Extracting archive: tests\\testthat\\CRF_Dan_Export_SAS_XPORT_2022_08_25_15_16.zip"
# [8] "--"                                                                                
# [9] "Path = tests\\testthat\\CRF_Dan_Export_SAS_XPORT_2022_08_25_15_16.zip"             
# [10] "Type = zip"                                                                        
# [11] "Physical Size = 14085"                                                             
# [12] ""                                                                                  
# [13] "ERROR: Wrong password : PAT.xpt"                                                   
# [14] "ERROR: Wrong password : procformat.sas"                                            
# [15] "ERROR: Wrong password : SITE.xpt"                                                  
# [16] "ERROR: Wrong password : TRIAL.xpt"                                                 
# [17] "ERROR: Wrong password : VISIT.xpt"                                                 
# [18] "ERROR: Wrong password : VS.xpt"                                                    
# [19] ""                                                                                  
# [20] "Sub items Errors: 6"                                                               
# [21] ""                                                                                  
# [22] "Archives with Errors: 1"                                                           
# [23] ""                                                                                  
# [24] "Sub items Errors: 6"                                                               
# attr(,"status")
# [1] 2
```

- in the build pane, `msg` does not contain the error messages, but they are printed apart during the testing process. Note that this would not cause a failure if I don't put an `expect_error()` in the test.

```r
# ==> devtools::test()
# 
# i Testing EDCimport
# Helper-init loaded
# v | F W S  OK | Context
# v |        18 | trialmaster [2.5s]                                                                 
# - |        21 | utils
# ERROR: Wrong password : PAT.xpt
# ERROR: Wrong password : procformat.sas
# ERROR: Wrong password : SITE.xpt
# ERROR: Wrong password : TRIAL.xpt
# ERROR: Wrong password : VISIT.xpt
# ERROR: Wrong password : VS.xpt
# x | 1      24 | utils [2.3s]                                                                       
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Error (test-utils.R:109:3): Extract zip with wrong password
# <edc_7z_error/rlang_error/error/condition>
#   Error in `extract_7z(filename, target, password = "foobar")`: 7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
# 
# Scanning the drive for archives:
#   1 file, 14085 bytes (14 KiB)
# 
# Extracting archive: CRF_Dan_Export_SAS_XPORT_2022_08_25_15_16.zip
# --
#   Path = CRF_Dan_Export_SAS_XPORT_2022_08_25_15_16.zip
# Type = zip
# Physical Size = 14085
# 
# 
# Sub items Errors: 6
# 
# Archives with Errors: 1
# 
# Sub items Errors: 6
# Backtrace:
#   1. extract_7z(filename, target, password = "foobar")
```

**What are the differences between the two environments? Is there a way I can reproduce the exact behavior of RStudio's build pane interactively?**

##### Repos

If one is so incredibly committed to answering, they can clone [this repository](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/EDCimport) and try both running `devtools::test()` in the console and in the build pane. Both take 5s to run.
Note that I didn't have the chance to develop this package on another OS than Windows yet.

##### Related questions

- [Difference Ctrl + Shift + T and devtools::test()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48230127/difference-ctrl-shift-t-and-devtoolstest?rq=1) (pointing at build options but this has proved not useful in my case)

Comment: What are the specific errors you are getting? That may help point to any possible differences.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44184068/devtools-equivalent-of-rstudio-build-panel-buttons

Comment: @MrFlick I edited my post for clarity, I hope the quality of the question improved. Thanks for the duplicate proposal but on the contrary, it tells me that both are supposed to be similar.